# Фильтрация в каталоге битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Необходимо сделать выборку товаров по параметрам.
Используются компоненты `bitrix:catalog.section` и `bitrix:news.list`.

Comment: Только компонента используется не bitrix:news.list, как указано в заголовке, а bitrix:news

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В настройках компонентов `bitrix:catalog.section` и `bitrix:news.list` есть параметр «Фильтр» (в коде — `«FILTER_NAME»`) этому параметру можно задать значение — название переменной, которую компонент будет получать и использовать для фильтрации.

Переменная указанная в этом параметре обязательно должна быть глобальной.

**Пример кода:**

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array(/*параметры для фильтрации*/);
?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news",
    ...
    "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
    ...
?>
```

Выборка в компоненте происходит стандартным вызовом функции `CIBlockElement::GetList` ([документация](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php)).

**Фильтровать можно по следующим полям:**

**По стандартным полям инфоблока**

*Пример фильтрации по ID:*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=ID" => 10);
?>
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=ID" => array(10,11,12,13));
?>
```

*Пример фильтрации по CODE:*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("%CODE" => "product_code");
?>
```

*Пример фильтрации по активности:*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=ACTIVE" => "Y");
?>
```

*Пример фильтрации по дате начала активности:*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array(">DATE_ACTIVE_FROM"=>ConvertTimeStamp(time(),"FULL"));
?>
```

**Фильтрация по полям**

*Фильтрация по свойству типа строка*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=PROPERTY_STRING"=>"VALUE");
?>
```

*Фильтрация по свойству типа число*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("PROPERTY_NUMBER"=>100);
?>
```

*Фильтрация по свойству типа список*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=PROPERTY_SELECT_VALUE"=> "Значение из списка");
?>
```

*Фильтрация по свойству типа «Привязка к элементу»*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=PROPERTY_BIND_ELEMENT"=>100/*ID привязанного элемента*/);
?>
```

**Фильтрация по свойствам привязанных элементов**

*Фильтрация по названию привязанного товара*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("=PROPERTY_BIND_ELEMENT.NAME"=>"Название привязанного товара");
?>
```

**Фильтрация по полям торгового каталога**

*Фильтрация по цене:*

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array(">CATALOG_PRICE_BASE"=> 4000);
?>
```