# Вывод элементов из подраздела инфоблока в компоненте news.list

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, компоненты, настройки

Есть тип инфоблока Каталог, содержащий инфоблок Товары

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри этого инфоблока есть разделы Телевизоры, Видео, Аудио и Товары для дома

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри раздела Телевизоры, Видео, Аудио есть подраздел Телевизоры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри подраздела Телевизоры есть следующие элементы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

которые отображаются в каталоге товаров на сайте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть также подраздел Стиральные машины в разделе Товары для дома

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элементы подраздела Стиральные машины должны отображаться на главной странице сайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я добавил на главную страницу сайта компонент news.list - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFaQD.png.

Как я полагаю, для того чтобы вывести элементы подраздела Стиральные машины в компоненте news.list необходимо задать каким-то образом фильтр (если я ошибаюсь, то поправьте меня), но каким образом его можно задать я не знаю (даже непонятно, как загуглить). Вообщем подскажите, как вывести элементы подраздела Стиральные машины на главной странице.
Привожу код вызова компонента news.list

```html
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    "",
    Array(
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "FIELD_CODE" => array("", ""),
        "FILTER_NAME" => "",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "10",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog_goods",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "4",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
        "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
        "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array("", ""),
        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "N",
        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N"
    )
);?>
```

P.S. Прошу предоставить не только рhp код, но и скриншот настроек компонента news.list, позволяющих вывести элементы подраздела Стиральные машины. Прошу объяснить предельно **подробно**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно указать параметр `"PARENT_SECTION" => 31`, где 31 - ID вашего раздела со стиральными машинами, но предпочтительнее задать для раздела код (например, "washing_machines") [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и указывать этот код в другом параметре: `"PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "washing_machines"`.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Тогда код будет понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода товаров и работы с категориями лучше работать с компонентом catalog.section, в нём можно будет сразу и указать категорию и вывести цену, остаток и т.д.

Для того что бы отфильтровать элементы выводимые компонентом news.list, необходимо указать фильтр. В компоненте есть параметр "FILTER_NAME" - в нём нужно определить названание глобальной переменной в которой будет находиться фильтр.

Пример:

```
<?php
global $arMainProductFilter;
$arMainProductFilter = array(
    "SECTION_ID" => ID_раздела
);
?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    ...
    "FILTER_NAME" => "arMainProductFilter",
    ...
?>
```

Данный фильтр будет передан в \CIBlockElement::GetList и полностью варианты фильтрации можно смотреть там. И подробнее описывал [в ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555084/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81)